# Error applying FAST ON COMMIT REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW IN

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

Error applying FAST ON COMMIT REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW IN.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW Prueba     
BUILD IMMEDIATE
--REFRESH COMPLETE
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
AS SELECT DISTINCT IMAGENES.TOTAL
  ,LISTAGG(OBDA.OBDA_DATO , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OBDA.OBDA_OBTR_ID) OK
  ,LISTAGG(ATRI.ATRI_NOMBRE , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ATRI.ATRI_ID) OK1,
  DAOR_OBJETO.OBJE_NOMBRE,
  DAOR_OBJETO.OBJE_ID
  FROM DAOR_OBJETO_DANADO OBNA
  INNER JOIN (SELECT IMOB_OBNA_ID,COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM DAOR_IMAGENES_OBJETO GROUP BY IMOB_OBNA_ID) IMAGENES ON OBNA.OBNA_ID = IMAGENES.IMOB_OBNA_ID
  INNER JOIN DAOR_OBJETO_DATO OBDA ON OBDA.OBDA_OBNA_ID = OBNA.OBNA_ID
  INNER JOIN DAOR_OBJETO_ATRIBUTO OBTR ON (OBTR.OBTR_ID = OBDA.OBDA_OBTR_ID)
  INNER JOIN DAOR_ATRIBUTO_BUQUE ATBU ON (ATBU.ATBU_ID = OBTR.OBTR_ATBU_ID)
  INNER JOIN DAOR_ATRIBUTOS ATRI ON (ATRI.ATRI_ID = ATBU.ATBU_ATRI_ID)
  INNER JOIN DAOR_OBJETO ON OBNA.OBNA_OBJE_ID = DAOR_OBJETO.OBJE_ID
  GROUP BY IMAGENES.TOTAL,DAOR_OBJETO.OBJE_NOMBRE,  DAOR_OBJETO.OBJE_ID;
```

**Error:**

```
 SQL: ORA-12054: no se puede definir el atributo de refrescamiento ON COMMIT para la vista materializada
12054. 00000 -  "cannot set the ON COMMIT refresh attribute for the materialized view"
*Cause:    The materialized view did not satisfy conditions for refresh at
           commit time.
*Action:   Specify only valid options.
```

Comment: Did you try simply putting the error message into Google? http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12054_cannot_set_on_commit_refresh_materialized_view.htm

Answer (score 1):

Fast refresh can be extremely difficult to enable.  There are [many restrictions on fast refresh](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#sthref237) and not all of them are documented well.

Don't be surprised if a simple query needs to be completely re-written to enable fast refresh.  For this example, you'll need to at least convert ANSI joins to the old-style syntax, and remove the `COUNT(*)` inline view.

After that it likely still won't work and you'll need to use [DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67191) to see more information on why fast refresh is not enabled.